# Could not find firebaseio.com

Tags: firebase, dns, hosting

the problem came when I tried to start to code for Firebase Hosting. When I came to step to Set Up hosting this step:

```html
$ firebase init
```

I cannot finish this step due to failed to:
HTTP REQUEST GET https://xyz.firebaseio.com/.settings/rules.json.
My computer cannot resolve firebaseio.com. I tought the problem was only occured in my computer. So I tried to other opinion, and I came to

http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=express&host=firebaseio.com
and
http://firebaseio.com.ipaddress.com/

Both also cannot find the record of this domain.
If you have ever experience this problem with Firebase, please share how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I just quickly tested and can access firebaseio.com domains without problems. Can you give this one a try? https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/43963770.json If that doesn't work for you, it is a problem between your machine and the Firebase Database servers.

Comment: Try to ping firebaseio.com & see what happens.